# Set result from previous Reducer as configuration parameter

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

As part of  the calculation logic , In a Mapreduce workflow i need to take the result from a reducer  as parameter for the next reducer in the chain.

```
    Path plc =new Path(args[1]+"/3");--> Outputpath from the previous reducer

    Configuration c4=  new Configuration();
    c4.set("denom", GetLineC.extCount(plc));---> GetLineC.extCount is a function that returns a value
    ControlledJob cJob4= new ControlledJob(c4);
```

Im using JobControl to create the dependency between the jobs and all the configuration. When  the program is executed it gives "No such file or directory".In the flow when the control reaches this part the file will be present in this location. But since the configuration is instantiated in the beginning this error is showing up.

Is there a way to set the single line output from the previous reducer as a parameter directly?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you mean previous job instead of previous reducer. If you're executing the two jobs using the same driver class, you already know the output of the last job, which is a directory. Clearly you're using only one reducer and it will write its output in a `part-r-00000` file inside the output path. To set it as a configuration parameter to the next job, you will have to read this file manually.

Are you considering that in `GetLineC.extCount(Path path)`?